# How to use ng-repeat in ng-repeat to toggle element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I some specific JSON and I have to ng-repeat over it twice, once for a parent once for a child. To avoid miss understanding I try to provide real data example below.

Array of JSON objects:

```
[{"id":"1fccb481-53a0-400e-8831-80acd1793bee","euroCode":"7812BGSHABW","position":"REAR","category":"REAR_WINDOW","glassPartType":"GLASS","description":"TODO: DECODE 7812BGSHABW","calculatedPrice":15768.00,"operation":"REPLACE","selectionSource":"MANUAL","linkedParts":[]},{"id":"71e1dc3b-47a2-4406-970a-ef0911c93396","euroCode":"7812AGSHMVZ","position":"FRONT","category":"FRONT_WINDOW","glassPartType":"GLASS","description":"TODO: DECODE 7812AGSHMVZ","descriptionByUser":"TEST DESC","calculatedPrice":5749.50,"priceByUser":574.22,"operation":"REPLACE","selectionSource":"MANUAL","linkedParts":[{"id":"0f45cd6b-7053-4625-8ec9-87281c126e1d","partNumber":"LSD","description":"LEPÍCÍ SADA","calculatedPrice":562.50,"selectionSource":"AUTOMATIC","enabled":true},{"id":"61bbbdad-1838-4327-8c38-8808a35a403c","partNumber":"string","description":"GEL POD SENZOR","calculatedPrice":87.48,"selectionSource":"AUTOMATIC","enabled":true}]}]
```

Here you can see that there are objects but some of them (in this case second one) have subobject `linkedParts`. Each of this element, no matter if its `linkedParts` or main element have to be on `<tr>` in table

How it looks for specific JSON above:

[image]

My code looks like:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="part in axCalculation.selectedParts">
    <td class="text-center">{{part.euroCode}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{part.modifiedDesc ? part.modifiedDesc : part.description}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{part.modifiedPrice ? part.modifiedPrice : part.calculatedPrice}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="toggle = ! toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="axCalculation.remove(part.id)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>

<!--linkedParts part start-->
<tr ng-if="part.linkedParts.length" ng-repeat="linkedPart in part.linkedParts">
    <td class="text-center" ng-class="{'line-through': linkedPart.enabled == false}">
        -- {{linkedPart.partNumber}}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" ng-class="{'line-through': linkedPart.enabled == false}">
        {{linkedPart.modifiedDesc ? linkedPart.modifiedDesc : linkedPart.description}}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center" ng-class="{'line-through': linkedPart.enabled == false}">
        {{linkedPart.modifiedPrice ? linkedPart.modifiedPrice : linkedPart.calculatedPrice}}
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" ng-click="$parent.toggle = ! $parent.toggle">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="axCalculation.removeLinkedPart(part.id, linkedPart)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                  ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-remove': linkedPart.enabled == true,
                    'glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt': linkedPart.enabled == false}">
            </span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<!--linkedParts part end-->

<tr ng-if="toggle" ng-repeat-end>
    <td colspan="6" class="text-left">
        <div class="row noleftpadding">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input ng-model="part.priceByUser"><br>
            <label>Desc</label>
            <textarea ng-model="part.descriptionByUser"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row noleftpadding">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="axCalculation.updateValues(part.id, part.priceByUser, part.descriptionByUser)" type="button" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you noticed at the end there is an `<tr>` named which should show when toggle is `true`

Issue:

- Toggle of the main element doesnt show below it when it has `linkedParts` ( what is obvious from HTML, but wasn't for me when I plan a code ). So **I need to display each  below element click comes from.**
  So correct one should be something like:
  [image]
- Toggle button atm doesn't work for linkedPart elements, click on that button just do nothing, but value of toggle is changing true / false.
  So **I need to fix clicking on linkedPart element display that `toggle <tr>` as well**

I know this is kind of complex question which will no be easy to fix but its more like to learn me think correctly. I will be happy for any advise or working example. Thanks, guys.

Comment: The linked parts will never be shown, based on what I see in your code. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Matheno its my code from like 1 hour because I do some mess from that time in code (while trying some crazy things), however it should be correct. Why you think it will never be shown? Only condition there is ng-if based on .length and when it have data length is greater than 0

Comment: I thought that because in the condition 'part' does not exist. The ng-repeat loop ended above the <tr>

Comment: Ehm please tell me if I am wrong but It actualy does exist from ng-repeat above.  Because this ng-repeat is inside another ng-repeat.  First line start with ng-repeat-start, but ng-repeat-end at the toggle <tr>

Comment: Ah never mind, didn't notice the -start

Comment: You do have a typo here : `ng-click="$parent.toggle = ! $parent.togargle"`

Comment: Moreover, if you could you ng-show/ng-hide/ng-cloak, it would help render linked part much better.

Comment: Hey, thank for this. I try to change it however no change happend :(

Comment: @Dev-One first of all thanks for trying to help me :) I already changed both of what you offer. Now it do 2 things:
1. First issue is still there
2. Toggle for linkedParts is opening correctly, however it open toggle of that main element not it own. I used $parent.toggle because I feel like ng-repeat have it own scope but maybe I am wrong.
I just try to use toggle instead of $parent.toggle and it doesnt work like that

Comment: can you create a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: @Dev-One I try to but I used there some directives and lots of different code so it doesnt work correctly with all that dependence. If it help I send link but I dont think so: https://plnkr.co/edit/67lB127xLwnQYjTZWjFh?p=preview